# Pass parameter to Execute and CanExecute relaycommand WPF MVVM Light

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light, relaycommand

I'm trying to use Relay command from MVVMLight and I'm struggling to find the right syntax to pass the parameter to both the Execute method and also the CanExecute method.

Below is my failed attempt

```
NewMessageCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(
    (obj) => NewChatMessage(obj.panelID),
    (obj) => (obj.AccessLevelCode.Equals(Constants.PANEL_ACCESS_LEVEL_FULLACCESS)));
```

Any help or direction would be most appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the actual type of the parameter if you need to access its members. For instance:

```
NewMessageCommand = new RelayCommand<MyClass>(
            (obj) => NewChatMessage(obj.panelID),
            (obj) => (obj.AccessLevelCode.Equals(Constants.PANEL_ACCESS_LEVEL_FULLACCESS))                
            );
```